# SQL identify the first name and last name, that is assigned to tasks to what company

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 Tables, new to SQL, I'm Trying to Combine 2 tables (Users and Tasks) into Companies or into a new table. What I need is to probably replace under Companies Table: TaskID and UserID with TaskID and UserID in both Users Tasks and table, but I get an error

```
SELECT COMPANY.UserID, COMPANY.TaskID, (FirstName+' '+LastName) AS FullName, TASKS.TaskSubject, USERS.UserID
FROM USERS, TASKS, COMPANY
INNER JOIN COMPANY.UserID = USERS.UserID
INNER JOIN COMPANY.TaskID = TASKS.TaskSubject
```

```
USERS:

UserID  FirstName   LastName 
1         John      Green 
2         Graham    Dale-Jones 
3         Francois  Peters 
4         Danika    Snow 
5         Jennifer  Booth 
6         Erin      Harvey 
7         Caleb     Jackson

TASKS:

TaskID TaskSubject     TaskManager
101      Install
102      Upgrade
103      Troubleshoot
104      Assign

COMPANY:

CompanyID TasksID UserID
1          101     1
1          101     2
2          102     2
3          103     3
4          103     4
5          104     7
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Please learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you first need to learn how to [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). What you are using is implicit join (on where) which is not best practice, instead you should always use explicit join.

```
SELECT 
    c.UserID, 
    c.TaskID, 
    concat(FirstName, ' ' ,LastName) AS FullName, 
    t.TaskSubject, 
    u.UserID
FROM users u
INNER JOIN company c
on c.UserID = u.UserID
INNER JOIN tasks t
on c.TaskID = t.TaskId
```

Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pwEyXgJKyzbZpRVmhnUwjn/0).